# Using pyinstaller to package selenium programs

Tags: python, selenium, pyinstaller, executable

I have a selenium python program I want converted into a single executable. In the program, I import various selenium modules, and I don't want the user to have to install selenium using commands such as `pip3 install selenium` I want these all packaged right into the executable. My program also depends on another executable through means of a file path.
How can I package the:

1. main.py file itself
2. dependency.exe executable dependency (referenced inside of main.py by means of its file path)
3. Selenium module

all into one executable? Any answers appreciated, can't find a guide to this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bundling data files with PyInstaller (--onefile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile)

Comment: How about a requirements.txt file? Like this: https://medium.com/@boscacci/why-and-how-to-make-a-requirements-txt-f329c685181e

Comment: @robscure This may work, but then the user just has to run a different pip command. I aim to have an executable which just runs, no commands necessary (other than the one to run it, of course)

Comment: I see, well good question. Just upvoted! I'm excited to hear the answer as well